# Error 030033 : Parameter does not contain a network dataset data element

Tags: arcmap, network-dataset, location-allocation

I tried to perform 'Solve location allocation' in ArcGIS and I received an error when I provided input road data to the to Network dataset section. It returned the following error: `Error 030033 : Parameter does not contain a network dataset data element`

How can I solve this problem?  [image]

Comment: Tell us more about your road data. Are you using a network dataset created from roads, or are you using the raw road data (polylines) such as Census road files?  Also what software and version are you using?

Comment: @smiller I added the road data above. I use ArcGIS 10.5.

Comment: It sounds like you have a simple roads shapefile or featureclass. You need to turn that into a network dataset to be used in the network analyst tools.

Comment: Assuming you have a Network Analyst license, here are the instructions for creating a network dataset in 10.5: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error and the screenshot you provided, you appear to be using a simple roads polyline shapefile or feature class, rather than a network dataset. You'll need to create a network dataset first for use with any of the network analyst tools. Confirm you have the Network Analyst extension enabled, and then follow the steps in this Esri documentation to create a network dataset:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-network-dataset.htm

The documentation is pretty long so I've only summarized it below:

> There are five main steps in creating a network dataset:
>
> 1. Prepare the feature dataset and sources.
> 2. Prepare the sources for appropriate roles inside the network dataset.
> 3. Prepare turn feature classes and add turn information.
> 4. Create the network dataset using the New Network Dataset wizard.
>
>    - The New Network Dataset wizard walks you through naming the network dataset, identifying the network sources, setting up the connectivity, identifying elevation data (if necessary), specifying turn sources (if necessary), defining attributes (such as costs, descriptors, restrictions, and hierarchy), and setting up the direction-reporting specifications.
>    - To open the New Network Dataset wizard, right-click a feature dataset or a line shapefile in the catalog tree and choose New > Network Dataset.
> 5. Build the network dataset.